# Select value with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sox

I have little knowledge of regular expressions, so I would like to know if you can only select the maximum amplitude value from this text returned by the sox program?
In this case, for example, I would like to select only 0.712219

```
Samples read:           6615000
Length (seconds):     75.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.712219
Minimum amplitude:    -0.805969
Midline amplitude:    -0.046875
Mean    norm:          0.009264
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000027
RMS     amplitude:     0.043011
Maximum delta:         0.734100
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.008353
RMS     delta:         0.041470
Rough   frequency:         6767
Volume adjustment:        1.241
```

Comment: Regex does not support aggregation constructs. You have to use some specialized language along with regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -nle 'm{Maximum amplitude:\s+(-?\d?\.?\d+)} and print $1' file
```

0.712219

This handles numbers with a negative sign and those with of without a digit followed by a decimal point and any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

`^Maximum amplitude:\s*(-?\d\.\d+)\n`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/1H15EV/5)

- `^` represents at start of line.
- `Maximum amplitude:` makes sure you have correct line
- `\s*` zero or more white space characters
- `(` `)` represents a capture group - what you want regex to return
- `-?` means optionally a minus symbol
- `\d` represents a single digit
- `\.` represents the decimal place
- `\d+` represents 1 or more digits
- `\n` represents newline character - that causes line breaks.

This was the regex101.com generated Perl:

```
use strict;

my $str = 'Samples read:           6615000
Length (seconds):     75.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.712219
Minimum amplitude:    -0.805969
Midline amplitude:    -0.046875
Mean    norm:          0.009264
Mean    amplitude:    -0.000027
RMS     amplitude:     0.043011
Maximum delta:         0.734100
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.008353
RMS     delta:         0.041470
Rough   frequency:         6767
Volume adjustment:        1.241';
my $regex = qr/^Maximum amplitude:\s*(-?\d\.\d+)\n/mp;

if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print "Whole match is ${^MATCH} and its start/end positions can be obtained via \$-[0] and \$+[0]\n";
  # print "Capture Group 1 is $1 and its start/end positions can be obtained via \$-[1] and \$+[1]\n";
  # print "Capture Group 2 is $2 ... and so on\n";
}

# ${^POSTMATCH} and ${^PREMATCH} are also available with the use of '/p'
# Named capture groups can be called via $+{name}
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/1H15EV/6) is an example using a named capture group of `amp`.

```
^Maximum amplitude:\s*(?P<amp>-?\d\.\d+)\n
```

Comment: I would only select the value 0.712219 in the fourth row.

By changing this way:

    .*Maximum amplitude:\s*(-?\d.\d+)\n

you select the whole row. I only need the numerical value instead.

Comment: You should look at the group 1 in regex101. Have not used regex in bash much. Bear with me. there's probably a way to put that into bash syntax.

Comment: OK thanks anyway. It's me that I have to study regular expressions well.

Comment: I think others have probably answered this for you now better that I can.. But in regex101, there is the option to convert to regex to a specific language. Tools > Code Generator > Perl for example too..

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in awk:

```
awk '/Maximum amplitude:/ { print $NF }' infile
```

This filters by lines matching `Maximum amplitude:` and then prints the last space-separated field of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Only print the line with a match and modify that line.

```
sed -n '/Maximum amplitude/ s/.* //p' inputfile
```